# Is there an easy way to draw in Elm using the L-system?

Tags: svg, functional-programming, elm, l-systems

I found little information about drawing using the L-system in Elm. There is an L-system library but it is not up do date really, all I have found that could be useful is a turtle graphics library (https://github.com/mrdimosthenis/turtle-graphics) but I am unsure how to draw with it using the L-system. What I have got so far is just a way to generate the nth generation of a sentence from an axiom and a rule:

```
rule1 : LSystem.Rule State
rule1 state =
    case state of
        A ->
            [ A, B ]

        B ->
            [ A ]


generateNTimes : Int -> (Rule State) -> List State -> List State
generateNTimes n rule axiom = 
    let aux state acc = 
                if n <= 0 
                then state
                else generateNTimes (n - 1) rule ((apply rule state) ++ acc)
    in 
    aux axiom []
```

I tried drawing using the turtle graphics library I mentioned above, but I am unable to see how I could use it together with the L-system.

Comment: Probably List.foldl will do the trick lol

Comment: This question is missing the "question" part... What is it you are actually asking about?

Comment: You need to write a function that interprets a `List State` as a sequence of drawing operations.

Comment: @JakubHampl you're right, so the question is how should I build up a function that interprets a List State as a sequence of drawing operations?, and would it be a good idea to use the turtle graphics library I mentioned above? The hardest thing for me would be to write the push-current position, push-current angle, pop-current position and pop-current angle commands.

Comment: @hunorg Why is that difficult? That's two stacks, and stacks are simple.